# How to save an HTML tag as string into database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a TINYMCE text editor and I want to store text in database.

But when I tried to insert data in database using Insert query I found the error like "A potentially dangerous Request".Form value was detected from the client

TEXT THAT I HAVE WRITTEN IN EDITOR

```
    for that i have used
    EncodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["txtcontent"]);
```

But it doesn't encode the tag..

Comment: May want the [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)? EDIT: Also, is it save to assume [tag:asp.net-mvc] since you've also supplied [tag:razor]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend using a `Model` binding instead of `Request.Form[]`.

For the actual question at hand, you'd want to add the `AllowHtmlAttribute` to the property which has the HTML.

Example View Model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even i changed my model with this AllowHtml attribute, data is still coming as plain text. Should i change the data type from string to htmlstring?

Comment: What do you mean by "plain text"? You should be getting the raw HTML as text?